# Trying add external libraries in jsFiddle

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

how to add external style sheet and javascript files and js files to jsfiddle

I am trying to add bootstrap style sheet library and angular library  but it did not show the bootstrap class's in jsFiddle

Answer (score 1):

**There is a an option "External Resources" at the left section.
You can include any external file there from CDN or other server if available.**

Answer (score 1):

Doc and libraries: https://cdnjs.com/

Bootstrap CDN is supported by `jsFiddle`, you just have to paste in the relevant URLs.

In the field of resources / external box enter each of these URL * and press

Link: http://jsfiddle.net/onigetoc/brqpaLv5/

Comment: Can you please check my fiddle i am giving you my url https://jsfiddle.net/Le2q4rxu/3/

Comment: That is how you are doing it. You must upload your external CSS and JS files to a server so you can share them in jsfiddle @MujtabaHussainBhat